# Cannot make model parameter from output destination in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a model that only takes in one user-defined object, all other inputs to the tool are (deliberately) hard-coded. In ModelBuilder, I wish to make two model parameters, the input object (which defines the extent of the final output raster) and the destination of the final output raster.

I am unable to successfully make a model parameter out of the output destination. I have set this as a model parameter but it does not appear as a parameter when I run the tool in ArcMap, and the option to clear the value in ModelBuilder is greyed out, see below screenshot:

[image]

What is the error in my approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apply Symbology From Layer Tool does not actually create an output, instead it references the input layer with the updated symbology. In your screenshot you can see that the Output Raster is automatically set to your Input Raster (MakeRas_a_and_s1). More information can be found here: http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00170000006n000000

If you want the user to be able to specify where to save the final raster you can add the Copy Raster Tool (Data Management Tools, Raster, Raster Dataset Toolbox) to the model and set your output from the Apply Symbology From Layer Tool as your Input Raster to this one. You can then set the Output Raster Dataset as a Model Parameter.

However, this will not save the symbology with the raster, just the data itself. If this is your intention then great - otherwise, without knowing a bit more about the model and its intended use, it is difficult to recommend a final solution. Regardless, I hope this information will help.